# Existence/uniqueness of closure of densely defined linear map between Banach spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, functional-calculus

Let $X,||\cdot||_X$ be a Banach Space, $A$ a dense linear subspace of $B$ and $T\colon A\to X$ a linear map ($T$ not necessarily bounded). Then $||\cdot||_A:=||\cdot||_X+||T\cdot||_X$ makes $A$ into a normed linear space. If we define $\tilde{A}$ to be the abstract closure of $A$ with respect to this norm, then we can naturally consider $\tilde{A}$ as a subspace of $X$, as $X$ is complete, so
$$
A\subset \tilde{A}\subset X.
$$
We can then define $\tilde{T}\colon \tilde{A}\to X$ to be the unique extension of $f$ from $A$ to $\tilde{A}$.

Then $(\tilde{A},\tilde{T})$ is a closed densely defined operator in the sense of Theorem 7.4.2 of Evans PDE 2nd Edition.

This seems to imply that any densely defined linear operator can be extended to a unique maximal closed (in the sense of densely defined operators) one. Is this correct?

The only references I could find dealt with Hilbert spaces and extending symmetric operators, in which case uniqueness of a self-adjoint extension did not hold.

Comment: Can you define precisely what you mean by "maximal"?  The closure of $T$ is its *minimal* closed extension, in the sense that every closed extension of $T$ is also an extension of $\overline{T}$.

Comment: But not every operator has a closure.  You say that we can "naturally" consider $\tilde{A}$ as a subspace of $X$, but in general this is not true.  You do get a natural map from $\tilde{A}$ into $X$, but in general it may not be injective, and so then you cannot identify $\tilde{A}$ with its image in $X$.

Comment: The $X$ and $B$s in your question seem mixed up: which is supposed to be the domain and the codomain?

Comment: Sorry about that, $X$ and $B$ should be the same space. In response to your second comment, you are correct, I missed that the natural map may not be injective.